# How to send SNS failed SMS delivery receipts to an HTTP endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

As far as I know, there is no way to directly send an SNS failed delivery receipt(of an SMS) to a custom HTTP endpoint; the only way I can think of is an intermediate CloudWatch log, which triggers a Lambda, which calls my API gateway URL.

What would be the most efficient way to capture an SNS failed delivery receipt at an HTTP endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that sounds right, although you should be able to directly trigger the Lambda with the SNS event (without CloudWatch log).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/application-event-notifications.html